# Reinstalling Mathematica pro on the SAME computer

Tags: installation, licensing

I am currently wiping my ENTIRE hardrive and reinstalling Windows on my (currently very slow) laptop. However, I don't want to lose my expensive version of Mathematica, and it looks like Wolfram is very strict about "new" devices. Will reinstalling my license give me problems?

Comment: Depending on what sort of license you have, the following may reveal the location of your license file: `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Licensing"}]`.  Back it up and restore it.  Then it will probably work unless your hardware has also changed.

Comment: This is really a question for Wolfram Support, though. They will be able to give you an authoritative answer on the matter.